# ini_set session maxlifetime doesn't expire

Tags: php, session

I am using this code on my loginsite:

```
if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
{  
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 60);

session_set_cookie_params(60);
session_start();

   if($fgmembersite->Login())
   {
        $fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("loginhome.php");
   }
}
```

So the idea was, that when the user logs in and presses the submit button the maxlifetime counts down a specific time (here for test purposes 60 seconds) and then deletes the session on any site coming afterwards the login. I tried it on loginhome.php, where I got kicked after 60 secs and had to log in again (so it worked here fine). But if i go on further, on other pages of the login area, it doesn't work anymore. I also tried to copy the code to every page, so that the timer works seperate for every page, which doesn't work.
Can someone help me?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Even though you set it to 60 seconds, it's not going to expire it on every request.  PHP rolls a dice every time a page is requested as to whether on that request it's going to expire sessions.  If you are in a development environment you can make that "dice" have only one number.  That is, it will expire and garbage collect on every request if you set the following settings in php.ini:

```
session.gc_probability  "1"  
session.gc_divisor  "1"
```